# Determining the purpose of a Windows process

Tags: windows, troubleshooting, process

In the course of diagnosing a problem, our attention is often drawn to a running process shown in Task Manager.  This raises questions such as, "Is this process legitimate?" or, "What does this process do?"   The problem with searching the Web is the dozens of sites that want only to bring you to their site and will say anything to accomplish this.  You've seen them: "Here you can find the explanation of clock.exe" or "Click here for removal instructions of SystemIdleProcess"

What I'm looking for is a straightforward resource that says what the intended purpose of a well known processes is.  For example, "This is Acer's trackpad driver", or "This controls how devices are turned off before sleep".

I realize these names can be spoofed, but I just want a first clue.  Seeing a process called wowexec might make you wonder...so it's good to know it really is part of Windows.

Comment: http://www.liutilities.com/products/wintaskspro/processlibrary/

Comment: [Black Viper's service configuration list](http://www.blackviper.com/windows-services/) is pretty handy for understanding Windows services. It lists the command line, including process names for standard Windows services and has a short explanation of what they do.

Comment: You can sometimes get lucky by searching the executable name (process.exe) online but there so many of them and many share the same name that it's hard to get at the right information. What I'd do is check the **Details** pane in the properties window (select the EXE in Explorer, press CTRL + Enter). Sometimes you'll find what you want here. If not, and the executable file is small in size, upload it to VirusTotal.com to find out whether or not it's malicious. You can also get the MD5 and SHA-1 hash of the file on VirusTotal. Searching for the hash itself might also give useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Doing some quick googling I stumbled upon a website I vaguely remember using in the past for just such a situation: http://www.file.net/ (click "Files" in the menu at the top, then enter the name of the process in the search bar on that page).

The information posted there by the site operators doesn't give much useful information, however the comments do. In the particular example you gave (http://www.file.net/process/wowexec.exe.html), users in the comments point to wowexec.exe being used to run 16-bit programs under a 32-bit OS.